# Click div to toggle inner checkbox

Tags: html, asp.net, checkbox, datalist, itemtemplate

I have a DataList with an ItemTemplate inside of it which creates the following ui:

[image: ui]

snippet:

```
    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" DataKeyField="Key">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="Row">
                    <div id="Cell">
                        <div id="Permission_Label_Div">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Permission_Label" Text='<%# Eval("Key") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </div>

                        <div id="Permission_CheckBox_Div">
                            <asp:CheckBox runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="Permission_CheckBox" Checked='<%# Eval("Value") %>' />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:DataList>
```

What I'm having trouble doing is allowing the user to toggle the check boxes by clicking on its respective div.I'm assuming since the DataList is an asp server control, I would have to wait for the page to finish loading before I can access each DataList item. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this should work

```
$("div#cell").click(function(){
        var checkbox = $(this).find("input[type=checkbox]");
        checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked'));
    })
```

Comment: I used your code and targeted #button_group. One click would toggle all check boxes. When I target #Cell, only the first "cell's" box toggles.

Comment: The issue is since I'm using a DataList with an ItemTemplate, I don't know how to target each item as they are dynamic.

Comment: modify div selector to target only the divs you need. smt like "div#cell"